# Using TypeScript makes apk size bigger?

Tags: typescript, react-native, apk

Since using typescript makes the code much bigger, does it make the production app bigger?

Comment: This is unaswerable as-is. What do you base this on? What have you tried? [ask]

Comment: And yet somehow I did get the answer I was looking for..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript specific syntax (interfaces, type annotations, generics, etc) are all erased at compile time. So the if you are writing the same code as you would in JS, just with types, your APK size will not increase as a result of using TS.

You might use different practices in some places if you are using TS (for example maybe extra guards if you are using strict null checks) but these usually improve code reliability so it is worth it.

Also you might want to profile your app to see the actual size of the JS code in relation to other things like assets, the big part of your APK is probably images and other native artifacts, not JS code. And even of the JS code you will find, most of it will be library code, not yours. So switching your code to TS, even with some extra checks will not have a significant impact on your APK size.

So if your only worry about switching to TS is APK size, you are good to switch, it is a non issue.

Comment: Thank a lot. I already switched to TypeScript and was wondering how will it affect the APK size. Did not find anything online about this issue so I hope your good answer will help others as well. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe not true, let say you have `type Animal = 'Super Long Dog' | 'Super Long Cat'` , then have a shared component that accept this type, then every time you use this Shared component, the type value you pass in wont be erased/minimize, the more you use this component, the more string in your bundle

Comment: so actually Enum might be more friend for bundle size compare to `type Type = 'string' | 'string'`